# Previous() method of the ListIterator class

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

My ouput prints `null` alongside with the elements when it should not. For example,

```
        MyList<String> l = new MyList<String>();
        l.add("A");
        l.add("B");
        l.add("C");
        l.add("D");
        l.add("E");
        ListIterator<String> iter = l.listIterator(l.size());
        while(iter.hasPrevious()){
            Object element = iter.previous();
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
```

And the result is:

```
null E D C B A
```

What's wrong with the previous() method and how can I fix that so it wouldn't print `null`?

```
protected Node<T> beginMarker;  // Dummy node marking the front of the list
protected Node<T> endMarker;    // Dummy node marking the back of the list
....................
public class AListIterator implements ListIterator<T>{
        protected Node<T> current;                
        protected Node<T> lastVisited = null;     
        protected int expectedModCount = modCount;
public boolean hasPrevious( ){
            if( expectedModCount != modCount )
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException( );

            return current != beginMarker;
        }

public T previous( ){
            if( expectedModCount != modCount )
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException( );
            if(!hasPrevious( ))
                throw new RuntimeException("Already at beginning of list"); 

            T prevItem = current.data;
            current = current.prev;
            return prevItem;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think we can answer without seeing the whole list class.  We don't have any idea how `current` is initialized, or whether there's something else in the code that causes the doubly linked list not to be set up correctly.

Comment: `current` in the `previous` method first refers to the *current* node, not the previous one: so `prevItem` is assigned the *current* node data. I suspect `l.listIterator(l.size() - 1);` would make the result "correct", although that is not a fix and just hides the issue.

Comment: Given the code shown, `previous()` should throw a `NullPointerException` because `current` is `null` in the expression `T prevItem = current.data;` If you don't get an NPE there, you must be initializing `current`, but doing it incorrectly. So, showing that code is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a dummy marker at both ends. This is because a `ListIterator` for a `List` of length `n` only has `n + 1` possible cursor positions (before each of the `n` elements, and just after the last `element`). Therefore you only need one dummy node.

I'd get rid of the `endMarker` and replace it by a reference to the last node. Then, when you call `l.listIterator(l.size())` you will get an iterator where `current` is initially the last node, so you will not get `null` at the beginning of the iteration.

Comment: Still gives me the same output :( @PaulBoddington

Comment: @KemalP. I've changed my answer. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your problem is incorrect initialization of current. When iteration begins (right after construction), current should be pointing to the last element (when the specified position is the size of the list), or null if there are no previous elements (position 0, or empty list).

You don't need a begin marker. Current will become null after the last call to `previous`, so you can use a simple null check instead.

You don't need an end marker either (it's not used in the posted code anyway).

Btw, the common exception to throw in case of iterating beyond the end is NoSuchElementException.